# How do I create a dynamic file path for Power Query for a file coming from SharePoint?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery, filepath

Context: I recently accepted a new job and I'm training my replacement. I've built a lot of reports for the company and a majority of them have been saved to my OneDrive. I've been moving these files over to a SharePoint site the trainee can use which has required me to fix the power queries in my reports so that when she refreshes the links in the workbook that it pulls in data from another workbook present on the same sharepoint.

Problem: I'm using the "Add shortcut to OneDrive" feature from SharePoint so I can access the files from my file explorer, so when I go to select the file it builds a path from my username, preventing her from being able to refresh the workbook since the file path is inaccessable.

Steps I've Taken: I read this article https://excel.tv/how-to-create-a-relative-file-path-in-power-query/ and I think this is taking me in the right direction except its from the perspective of all the files being located on your hard drive and not from a SharePoint site. When I enter in this formula into the file I'm sharing on the SharePoint:

```
=LEFT(CELL(“filename”,$A$1),FIND(“[“,CELL(“filename”,$A$1),1)-1)
```

Instead of returning the filepath with my username in it, it returns a https link (eg. https://sharepoint.com/teams/SharedHub), which power query then calls an error on since it's not a valid absolute path. Also, for reference, here's the code block from the advanced editor.

```
let
Filepath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Filepath"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Filepath & "The SharePoint File.xlsx"), null, true),
tbl_nexidia_Table = Source{[Item="tbl",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    tbl_Table
```

I also tried building a new query using Get data --> From File --> From SharePoint Folder but that seems to pull in all the folder names from the SharePoint and I haven't figured out how I drill down to a specific workbook to get data from a specific table.

Would very much appreciate some help on this!

Comment: I'll certainly be monitoring this post to see what solutions come along. I've never managed to get PQ to accept dynamic filepaths for SharePoint files, so instead I tend to run some VBA to determine the current username and build the equivalent local path dynamically. That said, I don't have the From File/From SharePoint Folder option on my version - I always presumed that that would have solved my issues. Are you positive there's no way to filter the results using that option?

Comment: I'm unfortunately not very experienced with Power Query beyond targetting an excel workbook and selecting a table from that workbook and applying certain filters to it. When I choose that "From SharePoint Folder" option it requires that you put the root link of the SharePoint site rather than a specific location, and then when it loads in Power Query it just shows a list of all the files from that SharePoint. I tried filtering for the file I needed but I couldn't figure out how to get it to pull something specifically from it :-/

Answer (score 1):

Try this. After you have placed your excel workbook into SharePoint, open the workbook from within SharePoint and then select the *Editing* dropdown and *Open in Desktop App*:

[image]

Then, in the workbook, click *File* > *Info* > *Copy Path*. (This will get you the path you need for power query to directly retrieve the workbook. It is different than what you would have gotten if you tried to copy the path using SharePoint's features for copying the path.)

[image]

[image]

Paste that path somewhere safe for reuse. Then close your workbook and open Power Query.

In Power Query, create two new parameters:

Click *Home* > the bottom part of the *Manage Parameters* button > *New Parameters*:

[image]

Change the name from *Parameter1* to *path* and change the *Type* to *Text*, then paste the path you copied for your workbook into the *Current Value* box. Then, from the path you just pasted, delete all the text that follows the last forward slash (/). Make sure you **do** include that last / in the path. You'll put the file name that follows the / in a separate parameter and won't need the *?web=1*.

[image]

***Don't* click OK.** Instead, click *New*, at the top of the Manage Parameters window. This will set you up to create the filename parameter.

Change the name from *Parameter1* to *filename* and change the *Type* to *Text*, then paste the filename you copied for your workbook into the *Current Value* box. Again, you won't need the *?web=1* from the original path.

[image]

Click OK.

Now you can use the parameters, path and filename in your source line. And here's how to do that:

```
Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(path & filename), null, true)
```

This will give you a table like this:

[image]

**-------------------------------------------------**

**For Mirza's follow-up, regarding pulling the files from the SharePoint folder, try this instead:**

1. In Get Data, select the SharePoint Folder connector and click
   Connect.
2. For the SharePoint Folder Site URL, enter your URL for
   your **root** folder for your files in SharePoint and click OK.
3. You may have to enter your credentials. If so, do that.
4. At this point, you should see a listing of your files that you have in SharePoint. Click the **Transform Data** button.
5. In the table that you see next:

   - Filter the Name column to the name of **only one** file that you
     want to open. (Use the dropdown arrow at the top-right.)
   - Filter the Folder Path column to **only one** path. (Same named
     files can be stored in multiple folders and you'll want to be sure
     you are selecting the right file by matching it with its correct
     folder, and this sets the stage for that.)
6. Next, set up the two parameters--path and filename--similarly to what I said in my first approach. But this time:

   - For the path's current value, paste the value from the Folder Path column of the table you're currently in; and
   - For the filename's current value, paste the value from the Name column of the table you're currently in.
7. Then, in the formula box for the Filtered Rows, change the name of the file (including the quotes) to filename and change the name of the path (including the quotes) to path.

You should wind up with code like this (yourdomain.sharepoint.com/your/root/folder/URL would be your URL to your **root** folder for your documents in sharepoint instead):

```
let
    Source = SharePoint.Files("https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/your/root/folder/URL", [ApiVersion = 15]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each (([Name] = filename and [Folder Path] = path)))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

You should see something like this:

[image]

Click Binary, in the Content column.

**-------------------------------------------------**

**For Mirza's second follow-up, regarding pulling multiple files from the SharePoint folder instead of just one file, try this instead:**

1. In Get Data, select the SharePoint Folder connector and click
   Connect.
2. For the SharePoint Folder Site URL, enter your URL for your
   root folder for your files in SharePoint and click OK. You may have
   to enter your credentials. If so, do that.
3. At this point, you should see a listing of your files that you have in SharePoint. Click the **Transform Data** button.

[image]

4. In the table that you see next: Filter the Folder Path column to **only one path**--the path of the folder where the files you want are located. (Note that this is different from looking for a single file, addressed in my previous answers, because this skips filtering by the Name column.)

[image]

[image]

5. Next, set up a parameter called path. For the path's current value, copy and paste the value from the Folder Path column of the table that you're currently in.

- To copy the path from the Folder Path column:

[image]

- To paste the path you just copied from the Folder Path column to the
  path parameter's current value:

  Click Home, then click on Manage Parameters, then if you haven't already created the path parameter, click new (otherwise click on the path parameter to select it):

[image]

Make sure your path parameter is set up like this:

[image]

6. Then, in the formula box for the Filtered Rows, change the name of
   the path (including the quotes) to path. That is, change this:

   `= Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Folder Path] = "https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/TestTeam/Shared Documents/General/"))`

   to...

   `= Table.SelectRows(Source, each (([Folder Path] = path)))`

You should be able to replace the current value of the path parameter with any other valid folder path within your root folder.

Since these source files reside within SharePoint, SharePoint's access controls prevail. So, for a user to be able to access the actual source files, which is what a refresh needs to do, the users who need to refresh will need appropriate SharePoint access rights to the source files in order to access them. However, I'm fairly certain that once the refresh has been done, any users who have access to your file that is built from this query's results (be it in an excel or Power BI file) should be able to see its results without them needing SharePoint access rights to the underlying source files. My understanding is that only those people who actually access to the source files, like for refresh, require the SharePoint access to those files. This has been my experience anyway.

Comment: Interesting approach, but does this (similarly) works if I wanna have files from folder itself? and is/can that possibly be dynamic (related to the paths if its shared)?

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of my earlier answer to see a way to use parameters to get files from SharePoint folders. My use of parameters is to demonstrate the passing of values through variables. Those variables should support dynamic interaction.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know. BEcause this was bottle neck problem cuz it doesnt have direct solution but some hardcore clicking around... thanks anyways!

Comment: Once you have the code part done, all you should have to do to use it for each new source is change your parameters.

Comment: Hi! I have been trying your approach of Dynamically File Path using from Sharepoint > From Folder...but this doesnt work for whole folder of files, that are expanding like in my case. You are here limited to "only one" file, but what if I am getting monthly reports, folder will be bigger and bigger. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mirza, Remove `[Name] = filename and` from the #"Filtered Rows" step in my code; so it reads as `#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each (([Folder Path] = path)))`. That should present all of the files in the folder to you. The `[Name] = filename` is what filters to only the one file.

Comment: Hmm okay, but does it work if some of my colleagues opens/refreshes this file actually? We tried and still my "name" is on the path...even though in my parameters is link from sharepoint.... 

Could you only explain in plain english this step what you wrote: 
"For the path's current value, paste the value from the Folder Path column of the table you're currently in"

Comment: @Mirza, I appended another answer based on your latest questions. It's at the bottom of the earlier answers. It includes screen clips for clarity. I addressed the following at the end of it, but your colleagues will need SharePoint access rights to the source files if you want them to be able to refresh from them, because in order to refresh from a file, they need to access it. When I'm working with folders, like you want to, I make sure folks have folder access rights as appropriate...not just file access rights...because the files change but tend to inherit the folder's access rights for us.

Comment: Just short update! There is no need for parameters to define actually. It is functioning on another PCs without any need for additionally job. I just tested with a friend, of course, everyone has SharePoint. I simply put a link from Sharepoint folder, did some short transformations and that is it.

Comment: @Mirza. The reason I included the parameters was because the *original* question asked about creating dynamic file paths, and the parameters are a way to create and use variables (the parameters) which are then used within the paths to facilitate a dynamic approach.

Comment: Yes I know. Thats what I say, it can be dynamic without adding any of the parameters. Only if its made from Sharepoint links and if both side having Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SharePoint connector for files native to Power Query, that will not use your username.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/sharepointfolder

Side note, you cannot use `CELL` function because

- in older Excel, user may need to press CTRL+ALT+F9 to update the calculation with their username, user will hate it.
- in O365 Excel, it returns the file url if the file is stored in SP. So you will end up using the SharePoint connector above as well.